# PHP I/O console

Tags: php, io, console

I've got an application (usual .exe file) that I can run in console (e.g. as daemon). It works fine and Input/Output is just standard STDIN/STDOUT so from the console (windows or debian) there is no problem. But I need interact with that with php (my php script).

That's again no problem because there is a lot of 'stuff' in PHP to do that (proc_open, exec, system, pipes, strings etc etc etc). The problem's that the application must work during getting/receiving data (in simple words -that's a daemon) but all the functions above waiting for the end of execution of the command and after return result.

> from php.net
>
> Note:
>        If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the
>        background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output
>        stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program 
>        ends.

It's known how to redirect to another input/output (eg. to file) with `>` `|` `&` etc.:

```
$last_line = system("myfile.exe>file2.txt", $retval);
```

that works fine even as daemon. Although I can't get how to implement an input in the mode.
However, my main problem how to redirect standard output to a non-file resource.
On php.net is written:

> Windows compatibility: Descriptors beyond 2 (stderr) are made available to the child process as inheritable handles, but since the Windows architecture does not associate file descriptor numbers with low-level handles, the child process does not (yet) have a means of accessing those handles. Stdin, stdout and stderr work as expected.

So it woud be easy just `command>&3` but I can't define new (my own) handles for I/O.

So the question is `How to implement/handle input/output (to BOTH ways) for a daemon!!!`

I've scrutinized tons of sources in Internet but didn't get a normal answer for PHP. It's elementary for Java, for example, for C/C++ but not for PHP.

Maybe somebody help me - I would be very appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `proc_*` functions are more powerful than you expect. Your assumption these functions will block is not correct.

After calling `proc_open` you can set every pipe to non-blocking. This will result in a way you can use `fread` without waiting for input from the process, and try to `fwrite` without waiting for the process to be able to accept it.

Also I would recommend to use `socket_select` to make sure you do not get into a tight loop trying to read/write to your executed process. A select construction will break it's sleep period when a file pointer (pipe in your case) is ready for reading or to be written to.

```
$descriptorspec = array(
  0 => array("pipe", "r"), // stdin
  1 => array("pipe", "w"), // stdout
  2 => array("file", "r") // stderr );

$process = proc_open('php', $descriptorspec, $pipes);

foreach($pipes as $pipe)
  stream_set_blocking($pipe, 0);
```

For more information see the documentation and comments of [socket_select](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php), [stream_set_blocking](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-blocking.php), and [proc_open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php).